# SQL Server : if...else based on row count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, asp-classic

This statement errors if there are no rows in the select statment (select top 1...)

```
update tHomePageWorking 
set nColumn = 2, 
    nPosition = ((select top 1 nPosition 
                  from tHomePageWorking 
                  where nColumn = 2 
                  order by nPosition desc) + 1
                 ) 
where nPosition = 1 and nColumn = 1
```

Is there a way to test the count of this statement and default to 1 if no records found?

```
select top 1 nPosition 
from tHomePageWorking 
where nColumn = 2 
order by nPosition desc
```

Comment: thanks for editing that I was just about to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the COALESCE function wil lsolve your problem.
It will return the first non-null argument:

```
update tHomePageWorking 
set nColumn = 2, 
    nPosition = COALESCE (
                 ((select top 1 nPosition 
                  from tHomePageWorking 
                  where nColumn = 2 
                  order by nPosition desc) + 1
                 ) 
                 ,1)
where nPosition = 1 and nColumn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is

```
declare @nposition int
set @nposition=(select top 1 nPosition 
                      from tHomePageWorking 
                      where nColumn = 2 
                      order by nPosition desc)
  update tHomePageWorking 
    set nColumn = 2, 
        nPosition = (coalesce(@nposition,0) + 1) 
    where nPosition = 1 and nColumn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @pos int;
select @pos=(select top 1 nPosition 
                  from tHomePageWorking 
                  where nColumn = 2 
                  order by nPosition desc)
select @pos=ISNULL(@pos,0)+1;

update tHomePageWorking 
set nColumn = 2, 
    nPosition = @pos 
where nPosition = 1 and nColumn = 1
```